# Parsing comma separated string with prefix

Tags: java, string

I am getting comma sepeated string in below format:

```
String codeList1 = "abc,pqr,100101,P101001,R108972";
```

or

```
String codeList2 = "mno, 100101,108972";
```

Expected Result : Check if code is numeric after removing first alphabet. If yes, remove prefix and return. If no, still return the code.

```
codeList1 = "abc,pqr,100101,101001,108972";
```

or

```
codeList2 = "mno, 100101,108972";
```

As you can see, I can get codes (P101001 or 101001) and (R108972 ,108972) format. There is will be only one prefix only.

If I am getting(P101001), I want to remove 'P' prefix and return number 101001.

If I am getting 101001, do nothing.

Below is the working code. But is there any easier or more efficient way of achieving this. Please help

```
for (String code : codeList.split(",")) {
   if(StringUtils.isNumeric(code)) {
        codes.add(code);
   } else if(StringUtils.isNumeric(code.substring(1))) {
        codes.add(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(code.substring(1))));
   } else {
        codes.add(code);
     }
   }
```

Comment: What about `R` in *R108972*?

Comment: There can be any alphabet prefix but only one.

Comment: According to your question,do you  want to also add data like `abc`? what is `else` used for?

Comment: Please what is the expected result?

Comment: I want to add add the codes. If single alphabet prefix found , remove it and add remaining

Comment: can you add your question and share the output, it's still unclear sorry

Comment: edited the post and added expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove prefixes from the numbers you can easilly use :

```
String[] codes = {"abc,pqr,100101,P101001,R108972", "mno, 100101,108972"};
for (String code : codes){
    System.out.println(
            code.replaceAll("\\b[A-Z](\\d+)\\b", "$1")
    );
}
```

Outputs

```
abc,pqr,100101,101001,108972
mno, 100101,108972
```

---

If you are using Java 8+, and want to extract only the numbers, you can just use :

```
String codeList1 = "abc,pqr,100101,P101001,R108972";
List<Integer> results = Arrays.stream(codeList1.split("\\D")) //split with non degits
        .filter(c -> !c.isEmpty())                            //get only non empty results
        .map(Integer::valueOf)                                //convert string to Integer
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                        //collect to results to list
```

Outputs

```
100101
101001
108972
```

Comment: Do you know what is `codes.add(code);` used for in OP's question? I think he is also want to add pure string like `abc`

Comment: @lucumt It is unclear what OP result should be, I will wait the OP to answer my comment in top!

Comment: Thanks for your response. it seems to be more cleaner approach. Thanks...

Comment: one thing, I was testing the scenarios and for this code (abc15), it is not working. it is removing the c and giving result as ab15. Can we handle this?? I only want to remove prefix if one alphabet is coming

Comment: @MananKapoor are you sure? check the [demo link](https://ideone.com/4iBibn) it return `abc15` for `abc15` !!

Comment: Sorry, for small abc15 it is working. But for ABC15 it is not. Can you please check

Comment: @MananKapoor in this case you can use word boundary just replace the regex to be [`code.replaceAll("\\b[A-Z](\\d+)\\b", "$1")`](https://ideone.com/xvLFZk) hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` to do it

```
  String str = "abc,pqr,100101,P101001,R108972";
  String regex = ",?[a-zA-Z]{0,}(\\d+)";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  while(matcher.find()){
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }
```

Output

```
100101
101001
108972
```

---

Updated：
 For your comment(**I want to add add the codes. If single alphabet prefix found , remove it and add remaining** ),you can use below code:

```
String str = "abc,pqr,100101,P101001,R108972";
String regex = "(?=,?)[a-zA-Z]{0,}(?=\\d+)|\\s";// \\s is used to remove space
String[] strs = str.replaceAll(regex,"").split(",");
```

Output:

```
abc
pqr
100101
101001
108972
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
String codeList1 = "abc,pqr,100101,P101001,R108972";
String[] codes = codeList1.split(",");

for (String code : codes) {
    if (code.matches("[A-Z]?\\d{6}")) {
        String codeF = code.replaceAll("[A-Z]+", "");
        System.out.println(codeF);
    }
}

100101
101001
108972
```

### Demo